# ASP.NET MVC - HTTP Authentication Prompt

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, authentication, basic-authentication

Is it possible to make my application ask for username and password prompting for it before render a view?
Just like on twitter API to get information about your account:

http://twitter.com/account/verify_credentials.xml

So before render the view || file it asks you to insert you username and password, I think this is made directly on the server since the curl request is based on username:password as well like this:

```
curl -u user:password http://twitter.com/account/verify_credentials.xml
```

As I'm trying to build an API following the same structure I would like to know how I can do this on ASP.NET MVC C#. I've already used this on ruby rails and its pretty simple like:

```
before_filter :authenticate

def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
    username == "foo" && password == "bar"
end
```

I don't think that [Authorize] filter is the same since I believe it's just a redirection,
and it redirects you to the Accounts Internal Controller that is based on the accounts database, in this case I will use another database, specifically from a webservice and do the validation after the information is submitted.
But I need the action to require the user and pass credentials on its request.

Thanks in advance

---

UPDATE:

Actually to request a page that requires this authentication (i.e. Twitter)
I would have to declare this on its request

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

And this would reflect that prompted username and password.

So, it's exactly the same thing but from the other side, if it's possible to **provide** information to the  authentication prompt on request, how could I **require** this authentication on the request instead?

So everytime somebody tries to make a request to my application on example:

http://myapplication/clients/verify_credentials

it should ask for a username and password with that server prompt
so to retrive information on curl for example it would be like this

```
curl -u user:password http://myapplication/clients/verify_credentials
```

Comment: Does the application use forms authentication too?

Comment: Actually the forms will use this external interface I'm trying to build, so all the validations and everything should be made on the request exactly like twitter without any graphic interface for it.
And inside my controller I will do the validations. I'll update my question with more details

Answer (score 49):

Well, to require basic authentication you need to return 401 status code. But doing that will cause the current authentication module to execute its default unauthorized handler (for forms authentication, this means redirecting to login page).

I wrote an `ActionFilterAttribte` to see if I can get the behaviour you want when there's no authentication module installed in `web.config`.

```
public class RequireBasicAuthentication : ActionFilterAttribute {
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
       var req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(req.Headers["Authorization"])) {
           var res = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
           res.StatusCode = 401;
           res.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"Twitter\"");
           res.End();
       }
   }
}
```

And the controller action :

```
[RequireBasicAuthentication]
public ActionResult Index() {
    var cred = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII
            .GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(
            Request.Headers["Authorization"].Substring(6)))
            .Split(':');
    var user = new { Name = cred[0], Pass = cred[1] };
    return Content(String.Format("user:{0}, password:{1}", 
        user.Name, user.Pass));
}
```

That action successfully prints the username and password I enter. But I really doubt that's the best way to do this. Do you have no choice except asking for username and password this way?

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much for your help çağdaş, but yes, unfortunately I can see that things are much more complicated when you speak about windows platform, at least is what I can say for now since, I'm not an expert on this. but this wont work since the request doesn't require username and password on itself, this would behave like a simple redirection and using curl on this url would result this instead a validation or not:
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="%2fAccount%2fLogOn%3fReturnUrl%3d%252fclient%252fverify">here</a></h2></body></html>
:(

Comment: What makes me think, if its really possible to build a REST API based on URL call with ASP.NET and it doesn't seems to be possible unfortunately.

Comment: This would only redirect if you have forms authentication enabled. I tested this with `authentication` part removed from `web.config` and it asked for username and password instead of redirecting.

Comment: I implemented ActionFilter and Http authentication prompted but I can't retrieve `Request.Header["Authorization"]` as I don't have or see such header

Answer (score 3):

You really want to create a service and not a web application, based on what I have read.  I am guessing here, but I think you picked ASP.NET MVC to take advantage of the routing and building the URL's the way you want?  Correct me if I am wrong.

In my opinion the best way to solve the problem you are having is to build RESTful web services with WCF if you are returning data.  This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx) should help you get started if you want to go this route.

Otherwise, you will need to go further up the stack for handling the request and authenticating it.  If this is the case, I can help with providing more info and code.

Comment: Hi Dale, actually I think your answer is very good, yes, I'm trying to create this API with MVC because of its facility and because the main app resides on it as well, so this API would be an extension to use on another platforms such desktop application, mobile phones apps, etc. I know nothing about WCF but it seemed to be very good, a I'm pretty sure that would worth to try it.
I seems to be much better than create a very complex structure to perform a simple job.
Thanks again Dale

Comment: And today we have ASP.NET WEB API, soon even to be merged together with MVC in one framework.

Answer (score 3):

I modified the çağdaş answer to put the whole logic inside my custom ActionFilter attribute.

```
public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string BasicRealm { get; set; }
    protected string Username { get; set; }
    protected string Password { get; set; }

    public BasicAuthenticationAttribute(string username, string password)
    {
        this.Username = username;
        this.Password = password;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var auth = req.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(auth))
        {
            var cred = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(auth.Substring(6))).Split(':');
            var user = new { Name = cred[0], Pass = cred[1] };
            if (user.Name == Username && user.Pass == Password) return;
        }
        var res = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
        res.StatusCode = 401;
        res.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", String.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", BasicRealm ?? "Ryadel"));
        res.End();
    }
}
```

It can be used to put under Basic Authentication a whole controller:

```
[BasicAuthenticationAttribute("your-username", "your-password", 
    BasicRealm = "your-realm")]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
   ...
}
```

or a specific ActionResult:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    [BasicAuthenticationAttribute("your-username", "your-password", 
        BasicRealm = "your-realm")]
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: The above implementation requires the developer to manually insert the username and password as ActionFilter required parameters but can be easily extended to make it support any authorization mechanism (MembershipProvider, ASP.NET Identity, custom userbase on an external DBMS or file, etc.) by removing the custom constructor and modifying the OnActionExecuting method IF block accordingly.

For additional info, you can also [read this post](http://www.ryadel.com/2014/12/08/http-basic-authentication-asp-net-mvc-using-custom-actionfilter/) I wrote on my blog.

Comment: Thanks, ideal for a quick and dirty solution!

Comment: You can even improve this further by deriving from the AuthorizeAttribute and overriding the AthorizeCore function. This way the Action doesn't get called if the authentication fails. Also it gets called before any other attributes. See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186425/best-way-to-abort-cancel-action-and-response-from-actionfilter

Answer (score 2):

Here's the way that has worked for me.  It's a little foot work but it will make IIS and MVC3 behave a lot more like all the other Basic Http authentication systems, like Apache...

Step 1.

> Make sure "Basic Authentication" is installed for IIS.
>
> > ( Example: Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off )
>
> *I'm using Windows 7 at the moment and am not sure the exact path. [GOOGLE: installing basic authentication in IIS] should get you close.

Step 2.

> Make sure Basic Authentication is enabled under your site. If you had to install this in the previous step you need to make sure you reset the IIS service and that all the app pools actually went down.

Step 3.

> (Note: I am using MVC3, and feel this should work in most models, including ASP.Net, without a lot of fuss.)
>   In your project you will need to add the following classes:

```
public class ServicePrincipal : IPrincipal { // This answers the "What am I allowed to do" question

  // In real life, this guy will contain all your user info
  // and you can put what ever you like and retrieve it 
  // later via the HttpContext, on your application side.
  // Some fun with casting will be required.

  public static IPrincipal Default { 
    get {
      return new ServicePrincipal {
        Identity = new ServiceIdentity {
          AuthenticationType = "Test",
          IsAuthenticated = true,
          Name = "Basic"
        }
      };
    }
  }

  public IIdentity Identity { get; set; } 

  public bool IsInRole(string role) {
    // If you want to use role based authorization
    // e.g. [Authorize(Roles = "CoolPeople")]
    // This is the place to do it and you can do
    // anything from load info from a db or flat file
    // or simple case statement...though that would 
    // be silly.
    return true;
  }
}

public class ServiceIdentity : IIdentity { // This answers the "Who Am I" Question
  public string AuthenticationType { get; set; }

  public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class ServiceModule : IHttpModule { // This is the module for IIS
  public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
    context.AuthenticateRequest += this.BasicAuthenticationRequest;
  }

  public void BasicAuthenticationRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;

    if( !ServiceProvider.Authenticate(app.Context) ) {
      // Total FAIL!
    }
  }

  public void Dispose() {
    // Clean up the mess, if needed.
  }

}

public class ServiceProvider {

  public static bool Authenticate( HttpContext context ) {
    // For the example we are going to create a nothing user
    // say he is awesome, pass him along through and be done.
    // The heavy lifting of the auth process will go here 
    // in the real world.

    HttpContext.Current.User = ServicePrincipal.Default;
    return true;
  }  
}
```

Step 3a. [edit]

> Here's the different libs you'll be "using"

```
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web;
```

> Just wanted to throw those in.  I hate it when folks leave them out. :)

Step 4.

> Add the following to your web config.  Please note I am including the surrounding structure, for example the "configuration" tag... It's just a road map, if you already have a "configuration" tag don't add the other or IIS gets upset with you.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ServiceCredentialModule" type="{Namespace}.ServiceModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
<configuration>
```

> Please note that the Namespace in {Namespace}.ServiceModule is the Namespace you put the classes from Step 3 into.

...and that's pretty much it.