# Adding basic authentication to ASP MVC action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, basic-authentication

I have an ASP MVC app that uses it's own custom authentication mechanism. However there is only one Action in one controller that I need to secure using Basic Authentication.

The idea is when the URL for this particular action is hit, the browser pops up the basic authentication dialog and then I need to have the username and password IN the action itself.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - HTTP Authentication Prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606991/asp-net-mvc-http-authentication-prompt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer which works:
[ASP.NET MVC - HTTP Authentication Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606991/asp-net-mvc-http-authentication-prompt/1607546#1607546)