# Best way to abort/cancel action and response from ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

Best way to abort/cancel action from ActionFilter

I've got this `ActionFilter`, and it's suppose to end the connection immediately and return a 401 Unauthroized:

```
public class SignInRequired : ActionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // User is verified, continue executing action

        if (Acme.Web.CurrentUser != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // End response with 401 Unauthorized

        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        response.End();

        // Prevent the action from actually being executed

        filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

I learned how you can cancel the action from executing by setting 'context.Result = new EmptyResult()` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609.aspx), but I'm not sure if this is the best way to flush the response and close the connection.

Comment: also wondering how to return 401. Although your solution works for me, none of answer helped me.

Answer (score 30):

Setting the response will mean the action doesn't get called.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)    
{ 
    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
}
```

As other answers have said, though, authentication should be done with an AuthorizeAttribute (Docs [for Web.API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) or [for MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)).

Comment: This will probably cause a redirect to the presumed login page. That might not be the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 23):

On .net core 2.2, 3.0 and 3.1 and .net 5 the below example works fine

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
  context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult("user is unauthorized");
}
```

Comment: This is valid on .NET core 3.1

Answer (score 8):

The answer that @OdeyinkaOlubunmi is correct for Web API or specifically `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute` but it can't be used for `System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute`. `AuthorizeAttribute` and overriding `AuthorizeCore` is a good way to go but if you use @Vadim's example for a GlobalFilter you will end up with the following error in a standard configuration:

> HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found The request filtering module is
>   configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

This is because the default `/Login?ReturnUrl=` will keep appending new values until the query string causes an exception.

The way I have solved it for MVC is like this:

```
public class DebugActionFilter : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
  {
    actionContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the result of filterContext for the Exception page like this:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Error/Unauthorized");
```

See more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) on section Canceling Filter Execution

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to make it an AuthorizeAttribute. That will set the result to be an UnAuthorizedResult automatically, plus it has the benefit of being run before any other filters. Alternatively you can set the Result to be a new `HttpUnauthorizedResult`

```
public class SignInRequiredAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return !Acme.Web.CurrentUser != null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using .net core 2.1 the solutions above did not work for me , so i tried this and it worked :-

```
 context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
 return;
```

if there is better solutions for .net core 2.1 i am open for suggestions

Comment: Just use return RedirectToAction("Someactionname"); Btw in 2.1 it is this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;