# How to set HttpAuthenticationContext.Errorcontext to Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Im trying to follow this tutorial: http://bitoftech.net/2014/12/15/secure-asp-net-web-api-using-api-key-authentication-hmac-authentication/

On how to secure a webapi with HMAC. Somewhere in the tutorial code it it gives:

```
  public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var req = context.Request;

        if (req.Headers.Authorization != null && authenticationScheme.Equals(req.Headers.Authorization.Scheme, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var rawAuthzHeader = req.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;

            var autherizationHeaderArray = GetAutherizationHeaderValues(rawAuthzHeader);

            if (autherizationHeaderArray != null)
            {
                var APPId = autherizationHeaderArray[0];
                var incomingBase64Signature = autherizationHeaderArray[1];
                var nonce = autherizationHeaderArray[2];
                var requestTimeStamp = autherizationHeaderArray[3];

                var isValid = isValidRequest(req, APPId, incomingBase64Signature, nonce, requestTimeStamp);

                if (isValid.Result)
                {
                    var currentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(APPId), null);
                    context.Principal = currentPrincipal;
                }
                else
                {
                    context.ErrorResult = new UnauthorizedResult(new AuthenticationHeaderValue[0], context.Request);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                context.ErrorResult = new UnauthorizedResult(new AuthenticationHeaderValue[0], context.Request);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.ErrorResult = new UnauthorizedResult(new AuthenticationHeaderValue[0], context.Request);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

I copied it of course, but mvc does not know about any unauthorized result with these parameters.  So this line gives an error: `context.ErrorResult = new UnauthorizedResult(new AuthenticationHeaderValue[0], context.Request);`

I can't figure out how to give back the right result. Does anyone know?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to abort/cancel action and response from ActionFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186425/best-way-to-abort-cancel-action-and-response-from-actionfilter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the wrong namespace. Should be `using System.Web.Http.Results;`