# How to halt executing inside of OnActionExecuting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

After checking for the existance of a cookie, if it doesn't exist (or whatever logic I have), how can I just halt execution and output a string response?

This is just for a small utility controller so I don't want anything fancy.

Comment: Possible duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186425/best-way-to-abort-cancel-action-and-response-from-actionfilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186425/best-way-to-abort-cancel-action-and-response-from-actionfilter)

Comment: OnActionExecuting's parameter is ActionExecutingContext now.