# How do Implement authorization in MVC4 Web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I Had create a MVC4 Web API. But People without authorization also can use it. 
Example: people type in address bar "/api/product/1" also can get the result.
So, How to implement Security and allow authorize person to use the WEB API only ? 
How to give authorize to the person that allow login to web api ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365373/asp-net-mvc4-and-web-api-authentication-authorization-windows-8-and-web

Comment: What type of authorization are you look for?  Credentials based?  Is your API public?  If you are looking to do server-to-server authentication you could look at HMAC based authentication which is quite awesome. This answer speaks about a WebAPI implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11782361/350933

Answer (score 0):

More info about [Authentication and Authorization](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)

Simply adding the annotation to your controller will do:

```
// Require authorization for all actions on the controller.
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id) { ... }
    public HttpResponseMessage Post() { ... }
}

// Restrict by user:
[Authorize(Users="Alice,Bob")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
}

// Restrict by role:
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
}
```

Comment: how to authenticate user to gv the authorize to the user.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here but I suppose you want a way to authenticate a user or role, those are in the article link, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use MVC4 AspNet.identiy.Usermanager and Microsoft.Owin.Security to authenticate user..

```
private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            }
        }


public HttpResponseMessage Login(string username, string password)
        {
            UserManager<TenantUser> userManager=new new UserManager<TenantUser>(new UserStore<TenantUser>(YOUR DBCONTEXT));
            var user = UserManager.Find(username, password);
            if (user != null)
            {
               AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicatioCookie);
               ClaimsIdentity identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
               AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, identity);
            }
                else
                    new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden) { Content = new ObjectContent<object>(new { Error = "You are not authorized to perform this action" }, Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter) };
       }
```

it is working for me....